# PHP Addition Subtraction Operation, Not Accurate Result

Tags: php, operation

`<?php
    echo 199.8 + 0.9 -200.7;    //expect 0, result 2.8421709430404E-14 ?
?>`

Tested on PHP Version 5.3.2-1 ubuntu4.7

Comment: There is a big warning about that on the [float PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php), this is called **Floating point precision**.

Answer (score 7):

Space-limited, fractional floating point [is inaccurate](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for some values (just in the same way that, in decimal notation, you cannot write out `1/3` in finite space).

`2.8421709430404E-14` is very close to 0.

Round it, or output it to a certain number of significant figures.

Answer (score 2):

If you want exact calculations (ie. for monetary transactions) you should use BCD (binary coded decimals) or arbitrary precision math. PHP has support for this using [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php).

Comment: yes but using bc functions has some problems as the example i comment it by replying on H3llGhost below

Answer (score 0):

Here some exact example with http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php:

```
<?php

$a = 199.8;
$b = 0.9;
$c = 200.7;

// set precision
bcscale(1);

$ab = bcadd($a, $b);
echo bcsub($ab, $c); // result 0.0

?>
```

Tested with PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze1 on Debian Squeeze

Comment: yes but applying the bcadd will give wrong values if greater than precission example

$precision = ini_get('precision') + 2;
(1/$precision + pow(10, $precision)); //normal add will return the number correct but without the float, return 1.0E+16
but using bc functions
bcadd(1/$precision, pow(10, $precision)); //while here will return zero

i see the example in [PHP Manual BC Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) and test it

Comment: You can give the precision as last parameter or set it globally with bcscale. There is also a bcpow. Where is the problem? Ah alright ... For that you can write your own calculator for the precision: For sub and add you can take the longest precision. For div and mult you must calculate both precisions.

Comment: ok in sub and add & mult i can put a specific precision since result precission is known but for div the result precission is unknown

Comment: The phpdoc says bcdiv takes the scale parameter: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php

Comment: yes i know but on add & sub the scale must take the longest precision & on mult we take the sum of the two numbers precission while for div what scale i can put?

Comment: There is no general precision you can take. You must set it to one value, because a division like 1 / 3 gives you infinite count of 3s. There must be a limit which is useful for you and after it you can cut.

Comment: ok, but i can't cut it because i need to compare them, i have equality condition compare.

Comment: You can try with precision greater than 1000 or something like that, but I can't believe that you need a so detailed compare.